# Sum of a exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I am working on a math question that I don't understand how to solve.

The question is as follows:
Consider a reception where the time Xi is an Exp(λ) distributed variable where λ = 10/h. Assume that Xi is independent and that there is no delay between customers. Determine the approximate distribution for the time it takes to serve 100 customers.

A:  N(10,1/10)
B:  N(10,1)
C:  N(10,10)
D:  N(100,10)

I thought the sum of an exponential variable was a variable with gamma distributed random variable. Not sure how to solve this question to be honest. Help appreciated :).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

- You are expected to use the Central Limit Theorem to justify a normal approximation
- What are the mean and variance for the service time of $1$ person?
- What are the mean and variance for the sum of the service times of $100$ people?